# Sleeping at Toronto Pearson YYZ airside?

Tags: sleeping, toronto

http://www.sleepinginairports.net/northamerica/toronto-airport.htm says

> A few free sleep pods are available airside. Unfortunately, we don't know the exact locations.

Can we do better?
I will have a five-hour layover on a really gruelling itinerary and I would be so happy to lay my head down for a few of those five hours.

Comment: @JonathanReez, you don't clear immigration if the incoming flight is domestic and the onward flight isn't to the US. Also I think YYZ (terminal 1 at least) allows immigration to be cleared airside now; the baggage system sends the luggage up only if they decide to look at it.

Comment: https://www.ihg.com/crowneplaza/hotels/gb/en/toronto/yyzca/hoteldetail

Comment: Is that airside? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: Which terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been quite a while since you asked (and quite some time since you've contributed, although I see you stopped by yesterday; you are missed).

An answer appears on [Toronto Pearson's Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/torontopearson/photos/looking-for-a-way-to-rest-and-recharge-at-toronto-pearson-try-out-an-energy-pod-/10153825958614663/):

> Looking for a way to rest and recharge at Toronto Pearson? Try out an energy pod from CIBC in our Terminal 1 Canadian departures hall.

[image]

Comment: Dark Helmet to the max!

Comment: "you are missed" -- replace the mods, I would be glad to be back. Has been so since Gayot and I left, didn't change one bit.